# R limit output of dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame of transactions.
I am using dplyr to filter the transaction by gender.

Gender in my case is `0` or `1`.

I want to filter 2 rows one with `Gender == 0` and the second with `Gender == 1`.

The closest was to do it like this

```
df %>% arrange(Gender)
```

and then select 2 transactions in the middle where one is 1 and the second is 0.

Please advise.

Comment: please provide code to make dummy data or at least the top of your data frame (`head(df)` and `str(df)`)

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% group_by(gender) %>% sample_n(1)` if you want to sample one random transaction per gender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To randomly sample a row/cell where condition in another cell is satisfied you can use `sample` like this:

```
# Dummy data: X = value of interest, G = Gender (0,1)
df1 <- data.frame("X" = rnorm(10, 0, 1), "G" = sample(c(0,1), replace = T, size = 10))

# Sampling
sample(df1[,'X'][df1[,'G'] == 1], size = 1)
sample(df1[,'X'][df1[,'G'] == 0], size = 1)
```

This is taking one value of X for each gender (condition of G being set by `[df1[,'G'] == 1]`).

Building from the comment by docendo discimus you can use the popular `dplyr` package, using the script below, but note that this runs considerably slower (5 times slower, 3M rows & 1000 iterations) than the sample approach I offered above:

```
pull(df1 %>% group_by(G) %>% sample_n(1), X)
```

Comment: Did you run a benchmark on data with 10 rows? If so, those numbers are useless.. you need a reasonable size data (at least a few million rows)

Comment: running with 3M rows and 1000 iterations it's 5x slower